# Error while finding element in selenium python webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I started with Selenium Webdriver and trying to open google.com and then click on button "Google search". I got the button element using `chropath` and below is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
b = webdriver.Chrome()
b.get("http://google.com")
c = b.find_element_by_name("btnk")
c.click()
```

Getting error as

```
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="btnk"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
```

Screenshot of chropath

[image]

Edit:

Below is the code to click on "I am feeling lucky"

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import time

b = webdriver.Chrome()
b.get("http://google.com")
timeout = 3
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='FPdoLc tfB0Bf']//input[@name='btnI']"))
    WebDriverWait(b, timeout).until(element_present)
    c = b.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='FPdoLc tfB0Bf']//input[@name='btnI']")
    print("Value of c ", c)
    for i in c:
        print (i)
    c[0].click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out")
```

This is working but why `c` is a list.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are not waiting for the view to be loaded before finding the element. You can use a [Explicit Timeout](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to wait until btnK is in the view.

Use the `WebDriverWait` until `presence_of_element_located`. The timeout can be adjusted based on network conditions.
It can be seen that in the html, there are two elements with btnK as their name. Although I do not know the reason for that, only one of them is visible, thus `c[1]` is used to click.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

b = webdriver.Chrome()
b.get("http://google.com")
timeout = 3
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'btnK'))
    WebDriverWait(b, timeout).until(element_present)
    c = b.find_elements_by_name("btnK")
    c[1].click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out")
```

Comment: why you are using c[1] instead of `c`

Comment: I started using css_selector instead of name. I am getting `Time Out` now

Answer (score 0):

If you see `DOM` you will find two elements for the input button with name `btnK`
and `btnI`
Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

b = webdriver.Chrome()
b.get("http://google.com")
#Close the cookie if there..If not ignore
WebDriverWait(b,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[text()='Remind me later']"))).click()

#Click on Google Search
gsearch=WebDriverWait(b,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//input[@name='btnK'])[last()]")))
gsearch.click()

Imluckuy=WebDriverWait(b,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//input[@name='btnI'])[last()]")))
Imluckuy.click()
```

Comment: what is `DOM`. Where you can see `DOM`.  I used css_selector also which also returned as a list although it was having single element. See my edited section of question

Comment: @Nitesh : If you go and inspect your element you will see 2 elements for the `btnK` and `btnI` where last element identifying the actual element.So if you use the xpath I have used this will work fine.I have tested and its clicking on element.

Comment: Does it returns list everytime although no. of elements in the DOM are 1. Secondly when there are two elements, how can you be sure that it is the last element. I know these are silly questions

Comment: @Nitesh : Sometimes you can find in other Website as well more than one same elements present and you need to identify using chrome [dev](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) tool which one is visible on the webpage.

Comment: @Nitesh : So when I check using Chrome dev tool I have found the last element is visible among two elements.Hope this helps.